# How to manipulate PDF files having scripts?

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF file with a form where you can enter some data and everything will be recalculated. The file has also some text fields I want to prefill with my own data from PHP.

I played with PDFtk. Unfortunately it is not working on my hosting provider and I can't install it there. And also even if it works, the scripting functionality of that form is gone after saving by PDFtk.

Do you know any good alternative to PDFtk or a method how to edit PDF files without loosing the embedded scripts?

Answer (score 0):

The [SetaPDF-FormFiller](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/details/) component (a non-free product of us) allows you to fill in PDF forms and also XFA forms with PHP:

```
// create a document instance
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_Http('filled-form.pdf');
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename('form.pdf', $writer);
// create a form filler instance
$formFiller = new SetaPDF_FormFiller($document);
// get access to the fields
$fields = $formFiller->getFields();
// fill in the fields
$fields['name']->setValue('blackhatmario');
$fields['a']->setValue(123);
$fields['b']->setValue(321);
// ...
// save the filled document
$document->save()->finish();
```

In view to calculations in form fields it may be required to force the calculation at opening time by a simple document level javascript:

```
this.calculateNow(); // in Doc context
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to work well. What are the requirments for the server? will I get a binary or a php class?

Comment: No binary nor encrypted source code but the plain source code is available for license owners! It's much more than a php class ;-) The requirements are almost default [system requirements](http://www.setasign.com/support/faq/setapdf/system-requirements/#question-121).